# Javascript collection of ids for form post without checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I'm designing a page which needs to post a set of IDs to a php script.

There is a table with a number of Items (with associated images) to select. Old school would be to put a check box next to each Item and post the form, then loop through the form post with php.

But the design is requesting that "no checkboxes be used". The idea being that when a user clicks one of the Items, that item gets highlighted in CSS then a button will post all the highlighted items.

The html looks like this:

```
<td>
    <table id="cell-5" class="change_back" onclick="checkItem('cell-5',5);"> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="img/5.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td>
    <table id="cell-6" class="change_back" onclick="checkItem('cell-6',6);"> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="img/6.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td>
    <table id="cell-7" class="change_back" onclick="checkItem('cell-7',7);"> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="img/7.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkItem(clicked, prdId){
    alert(prdId + ' was selected');
    var cur = document.getElementById(clicked).className;

    //if not highlighted
    if (cur == 'change_back'){
        //add item
        document.getElementById(clicked).className = 'change_back_clicked';
    }
    else{
        //remove item
        document.getElementById(clicked).className = 'change_back';
    }
}
```

the css:

```
.change_back {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}
.change_back:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.change_back_clicked {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;  
}
```

Thoughts on how to do this without jquery and with?

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery why did you tag your question with it? Here's how you can do it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: If the user selects an item and them wants to deselect it, what is the option for him ?

Comment: 'then a button will post all the highlighted items.'- is the button associated with any form ?

Comment: _"Old school would be to put a check box next to each Item and post the form, then loop through the form post with php."_ - opposed to that would be newb school, where one would try to "solve" this via JavaScript, instead of using CSS to make the checkboxes not _show_, but keep their functionality and accessibility, and highlight the associated image sibling using :checked pseudo class and adjacent sibling combinator ...

Comment: *1 I was asking for ideas about solutions with AND without jquery. *2 The user can "select" or "deselect" on any Item by clicking it. The css highlighting makes it obvious whether an Item has been selected or not. *3 The button is wrapped inside a form as are all the Items. *4 Javascript would not be necessary if using checkboxes and a standard html form. But that's not what the design calls for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I probably didn't explain what I wanted very clearly, so going with my own solution:

The javascript:

```
function checkItem(clicked, Id){
    //clicked is the table element that was clicked 
    //Id is the id of the hidden var

    //get the current css class of the table element
    var cur = document.getElementById(clicked).className;

    //flip the css class and update form
    if (cur == 'primaryCl')
    {
        document.getElementById(clicked).className = 'secondaryCl';

        //set form var to 'true' for form post
        document.getElementById(Id).value = 'true';
    }
    else
    {
        //reverse of the above
        document.getElementById(clicked).className = 'primaryCl';
        document.getElementById(Id).value = 'false';
    }
}
```

The CSS:

```
.primaryCl {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;  
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border:solid #6A6964 1px;
    padding: 0px; 
}
.primaryCl:hover {
    background-color: #3cb0fd;  
    cursor: pointer;
}
.secondaryCl {
    background-color: #3cb0fd;  
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border:solid #6A6964 1px;
    padding: 0px; 
}
```

The php:

```
/* css class set dynamically (code removed for brevity) */
$ibClass = "primaryCl";

/* hidden set dynamically (code removed for brevity) */
$hiddenTag = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"tp_$Id\" id=\"tp_$Id\" value=\"$hiUpd\">";


/* inside while loop, looping through query results */
$out .= "
  <td>
    $hiddenTag
    <table id=\"cp_$Id\" class=\"$ibClass\" onclick=\"checkItem('cp_$Id', 'tp_$Id');\"> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img alt=\"pic\" height=\"70\" width=\"60\" src=\"$thumbnailDir/$imageMini\" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class=\"b12\">$prodName</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>";
```

Comment: The answer I gave you fits your question. The selected element is highlighted and you can get all elements with the added class that marks that the element is selected. But I guess it's better to mark your own answers as the good one :)

Comment: The original question states "when a user clicks one of the Items, that item gets highlighted in CSS **then a button will post all the highlighted items**". Your answer did not address the form post, which is the reason for the CSS highlight switching. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: And where are this button and the form in your solution?

Comment: The htlm is dynamically generated by the above php code and wrapped by a simple form tag with a button inside '<form action="a.php" id="form0" method="post" name="form0">
    <button type="submit" form="form0" value="Submit">submit</button>
</form>'

Comment: But it's not in your answer! As it was not in mine. If you have asked for the form it would have been. I just made the selection. Then you get the selected elements with this class.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var group = document.getElementById("group"),
  elements = group.getElementsByTagName("div");

group.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ("DIV" === e.target.tagName) {
    if ("selected" === e.target.className) {
      e.target.classList.remove("selected");
    } else {
      e.target.classList.add("selected");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#group div {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
  <div>first div</div>
  <div>second div</div>
  <div>third div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stoycho Trenchev, some good ideas in your code, but the Items list is of an unknown length.